# how can I update a table but needing to get the update value from another select of the same table and other one?

Tags: mysql

I have this problem:

I have tableA and tableB

tableB needs to get the tableA's ID in a certain field.

tableB and tableA have a common field 'email'

Ive tried with this

```
Update tableB SET tableB.reference = (Select a.id from tableA a, tableB b where a.email = b.email)
```

Unfortunately when I run the query it says that I cant specify target 'tableB' for updates in FROM clause.

Any idea how to solve this or run a query like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableA, tableB
SET tableB.id = tableA.id
WHERE tableA.email = tableB.email
```

Or another one:

```
UPDATE tableB
INNER JOIN tableA USING (email)
SET tableB.id = tableA.id
```

Your query is also possible, but need to fix it:

```
Update tableB SET tableB.id = (Select a.id from tableA a, tableB b where a.email = b.email)
```

Comment: first option works very smooth, without making a select to get the value

Answer (score 1):

Update tableB SET ***tableB.id*** = (Select a.id from tableA a, tableB b where a.email = b.email)

Comment: Hello, is tableA the one I need to update, Ive also got confused with the field to update, is 'tableA.reference'

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to update `tableA` when you should update `tableB`, and also you don't need `tableB` in your sub-select:

```
UPDATE tableB SET reference = (SELECT id FROM tableA WHERE email = tableB.email)
```